# square brackets in Opencv and python parameters

Tags: python, opencv

I can't understand What is the meaning of square brackets  in  Opencv function input parameters ?
I tried to understand it by my self but I can't.
[image]

Comment: It's part of documentation right ?

Comment: yes, it is apart

Comment: optional parameters

Comment: thanks Miki for your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A square bracket indicates an optional parameter. Some optional parameters can be inputed only if the preceding optional parameters have been inputed. For example, you cannot input `delta` parameter if you have not inputed also `dst` and `anchor`. This explains why in the function description you have several brackets that opens before you get to the point where they can be closed.